# Externalised persistence.xml from property file

Tags: java, xml, jpa

I am using persistence.xml where is my db connection. And in log4j.xml  I have given `persistenceUnitName="JPAloggingPersistenceUnit"` which is in persistence.xml so it will take database connection from persistence.xml but which is hardcoded.

So I wanted make my persistence.xml dynamic which take connection from properties file.

I want to make persistence.xml dynamic which reads file from property file; like using `${username}` as key in persistence which take from properties file.

In log4j2.xml I have mentioned `<JPA  name="db-log" persistenceUnitName="JPAloggingPersistenceUnit"  entityClassName="com.majesco.digitalio.logentity.JpaLogEntity"  />`.

In persistence.xml I have mentioned below like
`<persistence-unit name="JPAloggingPersistenceUnit"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">`.

Comment: Which JPA vendor do you use? Ho do you initialize it (java code, spring, app server, etc?) If java, can you post some code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir....!                                                                     In log4j.xml               <JPA  name="db-log" persistenceUnitName="JPAloggingPersistenceUnit"  entityClassName="com.majesco.digitalio.logentity.JpaLogEntity"  />        And                     <persistence version="2.1"> am using sir please help if possible.

Comment: I dont want to used persistence.xml or trying to make persistence.xml dynamic which will take connection from properties file.  but my log4j.xml entry always taking connection from persistence.xml .

Comment: Follow this link , i believe this is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170876/persistence-xml-to-import-database-parameters-values-from-properties-file

Comment: thnx for reply sir but this was not worked for me ....!                                      The link which you suggest exactly I am looking for to make persistence.xml externalised from property file.                                              There are lot student and developer facing this problem but yet nobody was successful to resolve this issue . But I know you will definetly help me..!

Comment: Anybody have any resolution for this problem ..?                                                       Please reply friend...!

Comment: Hi mhasan sir do you have any idea about this issue ? Can you please suggest if u have any approach.